# BroadcastReceiver not receiving ACTION_ANSWER

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call

My `BroadcastReceiver` does not receive the broadcasted `Intent`. What am I missing?

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nrpreferences" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>             
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Receiver

```
package com.app;

import static com.samsung.nr.control.NRPreferences.*;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static boolean inCall = false;

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    Log("onReceive " + i.getAction());

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ACTION_ANSWER` [is an activity action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER), not a broadcast action.

Comment: I thought that must have been the case, though when looking at that page while writing the code i could not see ACTION_ANSWER on either list. I think the lists not being in alphabetical order is the reason. Well thats the one i'm sticking to anyway! ;-)